# Simulating RF interference (noise) to captured RF signals

Tags: noise, radio, interference

I have carried out an approach to clean my RF signal captured in order to perform classification on a set of devices.

However, a further extension to this study I aim to achieve is to evaluate the impact of a noise environment where these unintentional RF emissions are captured.

Is there a ***preferred*** approach to adding noise (i.e. Gaussian) to the signal to evaluate this impact? And if so, why is/are this/these desirable?

**EDIT:**

From Marcus' comment, to add some clarification for was noise needs to model is the impact of anything that would interfere with RF signal capture. My RF signals are captured at 2MHz sampling rate and fall within the frequency band of ~20kHz to 1MHz. So the noise could mimick that from wires, other devices operating nearby, etc.

These RF signals are captured using a MiniWhip RTL SDR antenna and recorded as IQ WAV format using SDRuno. These are recorded within a lab setting (with other PCs, testbeds, etc. in the same room).

The noise I wish to simulate would be similar to those in industrial environments (i.e. within warehouses or manufacturing facilities) which employ a number of devices, robots, power equipment, etc.

I understand that this may indeed imply a fairly large band for noise to accumulate in, or to simulate noise from multiple sources at different frequencies.

Comment: Hm. I don't think "preferred" is a category that makes sense here. What is it that your noise needs to model exactly? Put that in a few words, and people might recommend a good noise model.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've updated the OP to add some clarification, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Some clarity on your environment and the type of signals you're interested in would help. What kind of signals are you recording? What kind of devices are you using to capture them? Are you recording these signals over the air? Are you expecting specific types of interference,  or just Gaussian white noise from the receiver? What is the setting in which you're recording?

Comment: @Gillespie I've updated the edit in the OP. In terms of types of interference, there's no specific type expected. Gaussian noise was just an example I gave, as I don't have much experience in noise generation/simulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such "noise" evaluation is usually based on meeting a spectral mask for interference at the front end of the receiver but short of having that, a custom mask can be created to quantify the receiver performance consisting of a combination of broadband noise and narrow band interference with single tone and multi tone signals as detailed below.

Additive white noise is usually used to emulate sensitivity testing, where white noise (white within the occupied bandwidth of the signal) is added to emulate a received signal at sensitivity and quantify what is the minimum SNR that can be received for a given error rate (or other performance metric). This can similarly be done by reducing the received signal at the input of the receiver down to the actual sensitivity, but even better to compare this to a signal that is significantly stronger (but well below the maximum signal level the receiver can handle) so that a controlled noise source can be added. Knowing this, the performance at sensitivity with the receiver's own noise as the only noise source can be further evaluated with comparison to the known SNR applied. Further, we could increase the signal and noise together (maintaining the same SNR) to then find the maximum signal level where the same performance can be maintained. This would provide an indication of the "in-band" dynamic range capability of the receiver.

For interference testing it is much more common to use tone sources, called "Blockers" unless a specific environment is known in which we need to operate. A single tone in the center of an adjacent channel (spaced one channel bandwidth away) will quantify the performance of the local oscillator and  A/D clock since this test will cause the  phase noise on those oscillator to convolve onto whatever amount of the tone passes through any front-end filtering (if any such filtering could be that tight prior to the noise sources) and any amount beyond half the channel bandwidth would then land in band with no further opportunity to remove or filter, thus limiting SNR.  The same tone can cause front-end components to compress, reducing gain and therefore limiting sensitivity. The same test described above for white noise where the signal of interest is lowered to sensitivity and increased to its maximum value can be repeated with such a single-tone blocker test, ultimately reporting for the receiver the maximum blocker that can be sustained. A typical metric in this case is the 3 dB change from what was achieved with no blocker present.  Further for interest of evaluating compression, more detailed testing can include varying the single tone over frequency away from the occupied bandwidth and for each frequency determining the maximum blocker signal where sensitivity is degraded by 3 dB. This can be visually presented as a "sustainable single-tone blocker mask" that the receiver can support and useful for evaluating if further front-end filtering is needed (and if there are potential resonances in the existing filtering causing stronger but further away signals to bleed through and compress the front-end components).

Other common blocker tests that stress the linearity of the receiver are "Two-tone blocker tests" where instead of a single tone as described above, two tones are used with a spacing such that the third order intermoduation product of the two tones would fall into the bandwidth of the received signal. Two tones spaced by $\Delta F$ will create an intermodulation signal that is $\Delta F$ below the lower tone and $\Delta F$ above the higher tone when passed through a 3rd order non-linearity (one that creates a symmetric distortion to the positive and negative going amplitudes such as compression). So for this test we can place the two tones in the adjacent bandwidth with a spacing such that the intermodulation itself would fall into band and the testing described above can be repeated.

Given the prevalence of "Zero-IF" direct sampling architectures for software radio, it is also now important to include what I would refer to as an "IP2" test, or testing against sensitivity to 2nd order intermodulation products. This is similar to the "IP3" tests described above for the 3rd order intermodulation except in this case two tones separated by $\Delta F$ will create a 2nd order product at baseband at $\Delta F$ directly. If $\Delta F$ is less than the occupied bandwidth of the receiver, then two such tones applied anywhere in frequency could potentially jam the receiver if passed through a 2nd order non-linearity. To do this test, I recommend repeating the swept single tone test, where the two tones in this case are swept over a wide frequency range and the sensitivity of the receiver is measured. For each frequency the 2-tone blockers are set at, determine the power level for the two tones where sensitivity is reduced by 3 dB.

This outlines a comprehensive way to consistently compare the performance of different receivers and how they can perform in challenging environments with interference. If the interference expected is further defined (such as actual waveforms in adjacent channels etc) then these can be included as well.